# To what degree does reproducibility of research differ across disciplines?

Tags: meta-analysis, reproducible-research, research-design, academia

Have there been any statistics meta studies that compare the reproducibility of results, as well as the *willingness* of researchers to *provide* reproducible data, analysis, and code, in their studies across disciplines/industries (including, but not limited to academia)?

#### Background

In some research areas, very small numbers of observations can completely shift the outcome of a study, and therefore the way that data are treated (e.g. how 'outliers' are in/excluded) can have a very large impact on the results. I am interested to know which disciplines are more forthcoming with reproducible research, and which aren't.

#### Examples

Some researchers make their entire datasets, code and thought processes available on their website, their university/organisation's website, or on github or perhaps kaggle. But on the other extreme, some researchers do whatever they can to *hide* their work (like a black box).

#### Question

Have meta studies been conducted comparing the willingness for researchers to share their data, thinking, and code across disciplines, and if so, what were the results (i.e. which industries/disciplines were happy to share their work and which weren't)?